# "Clean" a python expression that has a \n

Tags: python, string

I have a problem, I save an expression from  a website that is for example "ab" in a dictionary... the problem is that the expression comes with an \n and alters my whole key, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm partial to string.rstrip('\n') - this way it only strips newlines, and only from the right end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [strip()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) on the individual entry/entries to eliminate the `'\n'`. If there are more than one or two, probably easiest to just loop through the entries of the dictionary.

Comment: The big advantage of a no-argument `strip()` is it will also get rid of `'\r\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to strip `\n` throughout, you can use [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.replace). E.g.:

```
# if it is a literal `\n`
some_expr.replace(r"\n", "")

# to remove actual new lines
some_expr.replace("\n", "")
```

An easy way to handle *all* whitespace errors (particularly if your strings are short), would be to split on white space:

```
"".join(some_expr.split())
```

If you only want to remove it from the ends, then you should use `str.strip` as @Levon suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [replace](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.replace):

```
>>> 'somekey\nwithsomenewlines\n'.replace('\n', '')
>>> 'somekeywithsomenewlines'
```